# BLE ability, secure connection and unpack data

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a use case, and i want to use BLE to accomplish the use case, i don't know if BLE support my use case and the way to do that.

Sensor Tag- is small device that works on coin battery and contains BLE.

Use-case: I want to connect the Sensor Tag to smartphone and unpack data.

1- The connection must be just to my smartphone app, i don't want any other app's to connect to the Sensor Tag and unpack data.

2- Each packet of data must be ACK, the smartphone get packet 1 and send it to the server, the server return ACK to the smartphone, the smartphone send ACK to the Sensor Tag, then the Sensor Tag will sends packet 2...

3- In order to force the Sensor Tag not send data in airplanes, the Sensor Tag must just listen at first, if he heard something from my android app, then he will sends connection request.

First questions: did the BLE support my use case? All, some(which ones), none?

Second question: How can i establish the use case?

Thanks.

Comment: Point 3 is complicated, because in most cases your sensor tag is the peripheral, i.e. the one that advertises. If you want it to react to your smartphone stimuli, that means you want your smartphone to advertise, not your sensor tag. Though it's probably possible, you'll have difficulties finding documentation since things usually go the other way. I'd recommend dropping this point and adding to your sensor tag an ON/OFF switch.

Comment: Thanks @TimF, but isn't smartphone automatically advertising when turn on the BLE?

Comment: No, the smartphone is most of the time used as a BLE Central device. In BLE the Central doesn't advertise, it just listens to the Peripherals that advertise and decide whether to connect to them or not. Some (or all?) smartphones can be used as peripherals but it's not the standard usecase and I don't know if it can be done with all the smartphones.

Comment: Thanks again @TimF, another question please, if i set the Sensor Tag to be BLE Central, and i could manage the smartphone to advertise, can i set the Sensor Tag to connect to only one smartphone at a time?

Comment: Yes, it's up to you to program it this way. But again, I don't recommend you to go that way. I think you should really consider having the smartphone as the Central, the sensor tag as a Peripheral and find another way to turn the tag OFF while in a plane.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot @TimF